# query data for count on second column

Tags: sql

Please create a query for the following data set . Result set should contain the count for country based on ultimateid

```
ID     Country   UltimateID
1001   us        550
1002   us        550
1003   ar        550
1004   br        650
1005   us        650
1006   us        650
```

output should be like

```
ID     Country   UltimateID  count
1001   us        550          2 
1002   us        550          2
1003   ar        550          1
1004   br        650          1
1005   us        650          2
1006   us        650          2
```

Thanks

Comment: Do your homework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is, contrary to popular belief, not a code writing service...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Using the microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0):

Select ID,Country,UltimateID, count([Country]) over (partition by [Country],UltimateID order by UltimateID ) as Count_C